# Opengl floatbuffer texturing

Tags: android, opengl-es, .obj

I am currently struggling to texture an .obj in java /android.

I have this cube as an .obj.

```
v 0.0 0.0 1.0
v 0.0 1.0 0.0
v 0.0 1.0 1.0
v 1.0 0.0 0.0
v 1.0 0.0 1.0
v 1.0 1.0 0.0
v 1.0 1.0 1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 1.0
vn 0.0 0.0 -1.0
vn 0.0 1.0 0.0
vn 0.0 -1.0 0.0
vn 1.0 0.0 0.0
vn -1.0 0.0 0.0
vt 0.0 0.0
vt 1.0 0.0
vt 1.0 1.0
vt 0.0 1.0 
f 1/1/2 7/3/2 5/2/2
f 1/1/2 3/4/2 7/3/2 
f 1/1/6 4/3/6 3/4/6 
f 1/1/6 2/2/6 4/3/6 
f 3/1/3 8/3/3 7/4/3 
f 3/1/3 4/2/3 8/3/3 
f 5/2/5 7/3/5 8/4/5 
f 5/2/5 8/4/5 6/1/5 
f 1/1/4 5/2/4 6/3/4 
f 1/1/4 6/3/4 2/4/4 
f 2/1/1 6/2/1 8/3/1 
f 2/1/1 8/3/1 4/4/1
```

This is the .obj parser

```
public class Model {
    private FloatBuffer mNormalsBuffer;
    private ShortBuffer mIndexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mVertexBuffer;
    private FloatBuffer mTextureBuffer;

    private List<Float> fTextureList = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private List<Float> fNormalsList = new ArrayList<Float>();

    private List<Float3D> textureList = new ArrayList<Float3D>();
    private List<Float3D> normalsList = new ArrayList<Float3D>();
    private List<Float> vertexList = new ArrayList<Float>();
    private List<Short> indResults = new ArrayList<Short>();
    private int indiSize;

    private ArrayList<GroupObject> groupObjects;

    // Android Stuff!
    private Context context;
    private int modelID;

    class Float3D {

        float x, y, z;

        public Float3D(float parseFloat, float parseFloat2, float parseFloat3) {
            x = parseFloat;
            y = parseFloat2;
            z = parseFloat3;
        }

        public float getX() {

            return x;
        }

        public float getY() {

            return y;
        }

        public float getZ() {

            return z;
        }
    }

    class Short3D {

        short x, y, z;

        public Short3D(short parseFloat, short parseFloat2, short parseFloat3) {
            x = parseFloat;
            y = parseFloat2;
            z = parseFloat3;
        }

        public short getX() {

            return x;
        }

        public short getY() {

            return y;
        }

        public short getZ() {

            return z;
        }
    }

    class GroupObject {

        String objectName;

        public void setObjectName(String string) {
            this.objectName = string;
        }

        public String getObjectName() {
            return objectName;
        }

    }

    public Model(Context activity, int mid) {

        this.groupObjects = new ArrayList<GroupObject>();

        this.modelID = mid;
        this.context = activity;

        loadFile();
    }

    private int loadFile() {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream;
            BufferedReader in = null;
            inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(modelID);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            loadOBJ(in);
            Log.d("LOADING FILE", "FILE LOADED SUCESSFULLY====================");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    private void loadOBJ(BufferedReader in) throws IOException {
        Log.d("LOADING FILE", "STARTING!====================");
        GroupObject defaultObject = new GroupObject();
        GroupObject currentObject = defaultObject;

        this.groupObjects.add(defaultObject);

        String Line = null; // Stores ever line we read!
        String[] Blocks; // Stores string fragments after the split!!
        String CommandBlock; // Stores Command Blocks such as: v, vt, vn, g,
                                // etc...
        try {
            while ((Line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                Line = Line.trim();
                Blocks = Line.split(" ");
                CommandBlock = Blocks[0];
                if (CommandBlock.equals("g")) {
                    if (Blocks[1] == "default")
                        currentObject = defaultObject;
                    else {
                        GroupObject groupObject = new GroupObject();
                        groupObject.setObjectName(Blocks[1]);
                        currentObject = groupObject;
                        groupObjects.add(groupObject);
                    }
                }

                if (CommandBlock.equals("v")) {
                    vertexList.add(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]));
                    vertexList.add(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]));
                    vertexList.add(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3]));
                }

                if (CommandBlock.equals("vt")) {
                    textureList.add(new Float3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]), 0.0f));
                }

                if (CommandBlock.equals("vn")) {
                    normalsList.add(new Float3D(Float.parseFloat(Blocks[1]), Float.parseFloat(Blocks[2]),
                            Float.parseFloat(Blocks[3])));
                }

                if (CommandBlock.equals("f")) {

                    if (Blocks.length == 4) {
                        // faces with just 3 vert per face
                        for (int i = 1; i < Blocks.length; i++) {
                            short m = 1;
                            String[] values = Blocks[i].split("/");
                            short vn = Short.parseShort(values[2]);
                            short vt = Short.parseShort(values[1]);
                            short temp = Short.parseShort(values[0]);
                            temp = (short) (temp - m);

                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(vn - m).x);
                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(vn - m).y);
                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(vn - m).z);

                            fTextureList.add(textureList.get(vt - m).x);
                            fTextureList.add(textureList.get(vt - m).y);

                            indResults.add(temp);
                            indiSize++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // faces with 4 vert per face
                        Short3D[] indexTemp = new Short3D[4];
                        for (int i = 1; i < Blocks.length; i++) {
                            short m = 1;
                            String[] values = Blocks[i].split("/");
                            short vn = Short.parseShort(values[2]);
                            short vt = Short.parseShort(values[1]);
                            short temp = Short.parseShort(values[0]);
                            temp = (short) (temp - m);
                            Short3D fTemp = new Short3D(temp, vt, vn);
                            indexTemp[i - 1] = fTemp;
                        }

                        Short3D[] newFaceIndex = convertQuads(indexTemp);
                        short m = 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < newFaceIndex.length; i++) {

                            indResults.add(newFaceIndex[i].x);

                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(newFaceIndex[i].z - m).x);
                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(newFaceIndex[i].z - m).y);
                            fNormalsList.add(normalsList.get(newFaceIndex[i].z - m).z);

                            fTextureList.add(textureList.get(newFaceIndex[i].y - m).x);
                            fTextureList.add(textureList.get(newFaceIndex[i].y - m).y);
                            fTextureList.add(textureList.get(newFaceIndex[i].y - m).z);

                            indiSize++;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            System.out.println("done loading");
            float[] vertResults = new float[vertexList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexList.size(); i++) {
                vertResults[i] = vertexList.get(i);
            }
            mVertexBuffer = RenderUtils.buildFloatBuffer(vertResults);

            short[] indctemp = new short[indResults.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < indResults.size(); i++) {
                indctemp[i] = indResults.get(i);
            }
            mIndexBuffer = RenderUtils.buildShortBuffer(indctemp);

            float[] normTemp = new float[fNormalsList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < fTextureList.size(); i++) {
                normTemp[i] = fNormalsList.get(i);
            }
            mNormalsBuffer = RenderUtils.buildFloatBuffer(normTemp);

            float[] texTemp = new float[fTextureList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < fTextureList.size(); i++) {
                texTemp[i] = fTextureList.get(i);
                // System.out.println(texTemp[i]+",");
            }
            mTextureBuffer = RenderUtils.buildFloatBuffer(texTemp);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println(Line);
        }
    }

    public int getIndSize() {
        return this.indiSize;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getVertices() {
        return mVertexBuffer;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getTexCoords() {
        return mTextureBuffer;
    }

    public ShortBuffer getIndices() {
        return mIndexBuffer;
    }

    public FloatBuffer getNormals() {
        return mNormalsBuffer;
    }

    public Short3D[] convertQuads(Short3D[] vert) {
        Short3D[] newVert = new Short3D[6];
        newVert[0] = vert[0];
        newVert[1] = vert[1];
        newVert[2] = vert[2];
        newVert[3] = vert[0];
        newVert[4] = vert[2];
        newVert[5] = vert[3];

        return newVert;
    }
}
```

this is the texture loading and the draw method of the 3d object:

```
public void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int texid) {
        // loading texture
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                texid);

        // generate one texture pointer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();
    }



    public void draw(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        // GLES10.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GLES10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);
        gl.glNormalPointer(GLES10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mNormalBuffer);
        gl.glDrawElements(GLES10.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getIndSize(), GLES10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mIndices);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTextureBuffer);

        // GLES10.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glDisableClientState(GLES10.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    }
```

And finally the drawing method of the renderer:

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {

        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().getProjectionMatrix(), 0);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);        
        //gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CW);

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);

        if (ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerVisible(markerID)) {        

            gl.glLoadMatrixf(ARToolKit.getInstance().queryMarkerTransformation(markerID), 0);

            gl.glPushMatrix(); 
            gl.glRotatef(-90f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef(90f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            gl.glRotatef(-90f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
            gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);  
            gl.glScalef(40, 40, 40);
            //gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 20);
            shoe.draw(gl);
            //cube.draw(gl);
            gl.glPopMatrix();

            if (spinning) angle += 5.0f;
        }
```

the texture is somehow displayed but is really messy stretched over the cube and not displayed on each side ..... what am I missing ?   The texturebuffer looks correct to me. 
Thanks in advance for any ideas.
Cheers

Comment: First you build 3 arrays with v,vn and vt, than your parse the f, 1/1/2 is the first vertex of the first triangle which has vertex[1], normal[1], and textureCoord[2]=> you take those 3 values, and you create a brand new array with it as your first vertice

Comment: example code: https://github.com/jpbruyere/GGL/blob/ottd/Tetra/Mesh.cs

Comment: maybe your fragment shader use gl_FragCoord instead of inTexCoord, without more code...hard to say

Comment: Thanks mate, Ill try this tomorrow, sounds very plausible, and would explain why my lighting is messy too :D , I just passed the vn and vt directly as buffers without parsing the f

Comment: sorry still not working and i updated the question with more code

Comment: you draw unsigned short indices, your indice array have to be also unsigned short, but it's not a problem for now...

Comment: so any idea why this texture is not displayed correctly?